# Error with delete statement in jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I did a lot of search work for finding out the error. I found the same error by many other learners but it was for the insert statement. However my question seems to be searching the question for delete statement. I have got the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [delete from tbl_cust where Cust_id=2]; Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

However when i query same sql in localhost/phpmyadmin/ it would delete record with no error 
I have tried some of the following:

```
public int delete(int id) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    String sql= "DELETE FROM tbl_cust WHERE Cust="+id;
    Object[] obj={id};
    return JdbcTemplate.update(sql,obj);
}
```

This is the next example

```
 public int delete(int id) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    String sql= "DELETE FROM tbl_cust WHERE Cust_id=?";
    Object[] obj={id};
    return JdbcTemplate.update(sql,obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  getSimpleJdbcTemplate() instead of JdbcTemplate

```
public void deleterecord(int hostId)
{
String sql= "DELETE FROM tbl_cust WHERE Cust_id=?";
getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update(sql, hostId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use update method from JdbcTemplate. Replace the line jdbcTemplate.update(sql,obj) with **jdbcTemplate.update(sql,id)**

Also, fyi, update does all the below operations:

1. Update
2. Delete
3. Insert

Comment: Can you copy the error or print the stack trace, so we can look in detail what's really going on..  please also include any further details you think would require to tackle this error.

Comment: I have edited my question by adding the error I was getting

Comment: If you are using the statement **"DELETE FROM tbl_cust WHERE Cust_id=?"**, apparently it should work. Now may you need to debug and see if that statement is holding the expected value in its parameter.

Comment: Any luck with debugging?

Comment: Luckily It suceeded

Comment: Great, so what was the issue? You can post your answer if its different from this or mark the corresponding answer as correct